# Error code:10021, error message: "Uncaught TypeError: n(...).connect is not a function"

Tags: node.js, webpack, mongoose, serverless, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to use mongoose package with Cloudflare workers.
After webpack When I am deploying with serverless deploy I am getting this Error message.

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: deploying route: example.com/api
Serverless: ❌  Fatal Error, Script Not Deployed!
Serverless: --> Error Code:10021
--> Error Message: "Uncaught TypeError: n(...).connect is not a function
at line 950
at line 1 in n
at line 1
at line 1
"
Serverless: ✅  Routes Deployed
```

On Line 950

```
n(83).connect("mongodb://localhost/db",........
```

my main code is

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/db", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

async function handleRequest(r) {
  return new Response(r);
}
```

I tried mongodb package too.
Shows same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These packages assume you are running on Node.js and they use Node.js APIs. Cloudflare Workers is not based on Node.js. Instead, it implements a subset of the Web Platform APIs, especially the Service Workers API.

At present, you cannot create a TCP connection from a Worker, thus you cannot connect directly to a Mongo server. Instead, you will need to formulate your database queries as HTTP requests using the `fetch()` API.